# JavaScript to Java to MYSQL Query

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, angularjs

I have a Java API Crud, with simple queries like "get a single item or a list of items" works great, the problem is when I need to do a more complex query and pass a list of values for the api to apply a more complex filter to the data it returns from the mysql table.

I have a table called "hours" which contains data like this:

```
[{"id":1,"hour":"08:00"},{"id":2,"hour":"08:05"},{"id":3,"hour":"08:10"},{"hour":4,"hora":"08:15"},{"id":5,"hour":"08:20"}]
```

And a table called "turns" which contains data like this:

```
 [{"id":1,"solicitante":"asdasdas","telefono":null,"tipoDocumento":{"id":1,"tipodoc":"Dni"},"numeroDocumento":"32821535","email":null,"hours":{"id":1,"hour":"08:00"},"numeroTurno":"A1001","fecha":"2016-02-02","controlFecha":"2016-02-11 18:27:52.0","formatFecha":"2016-02-02"},{"id":10,"solicitante":"asddasdas asdasdas","telefono":null,"tipoDocumento":{"id":1,"tipodoc":"Dni"},"numeroDocumento":"2331312","email":null,"hours":{"id":2,"hour":"08:05"},"numeroTurno":"A1002","fecha":"2016-02-02","controlFecha":"2016-02-11 18:27:52.0","formatFecha":"2016-02-02"}]
```

What I'm trying to do is a query to return the not taken "hours" for a particular day.
Wasn't quite sure how to do this so I tried something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/hours/{takenHours}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public List<Hours> queryHours(@RequestParam(value = "takenHours") List<String> takenHours) {
    List<Hours> hours = hoursService.getHours(takenHours);
    return hours;
}   

 @Override
public List<Hours> getHours(List<String> takenHours) {
    List<Hours> hours = hoursRepository.findByHourNotIn(takenHours);
    return hours;
}
```

So I made a query for a particular day, return all the hour's taken and try to send the array to this method.
I'll add the date filter later (findByHoraNotInAndDate).

Not sure if this is the best approach, will gladly take any ideas.

I'm using AngularJS to handle the front-end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed changing the way i was approcahing the problem.

Made a list of hours in minutes then formated it and thrown it to the controller using simple for loop.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "horario")
public class Horario implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Long id;
private Integer dia;
private Integer horarioInicio;
private Integer horarioFin;
private Integer duration;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "id")
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name = "dia")
public Integer getDia() {
    return dia;
}

public void setDia(Integer dia) {
    this.dia = dia;
}

@Column(name = "horario_inicio")
public Integer getHorarioInicio() {
    return horarioInicio;
}

public void setHorarioInicio(Integer horarioInicio) {
    this.horarioInicio = horarioInicio;
}

@Column(name = "horario_fin")
public Integer getHorarioFin() {
    return horarioFin;
}

public void setHorarioFin(Integer horarioFin) {
    this.horarioFin = horarioFin;
}

@Transient
public List<Integer> getHorarios(){
    List<Integer> horarios = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(Integer i = horarioInicio; i <= horarioFin; i+=duration){
        horarios.add(i);
    }
    return horarios;
}

@Column(name = "duration")
public Integer getDuration() {
    return duration;
}

public void setDuration(Integer duration) {
    this.duration = duration;
}

@Transient
public List<String> getHorariosLibres(List<Integer> horariosTomados){

    List<Integer> horariosTemporal = getHorarios();
    horariosTemporal.removeAll(horariosTomados);
    List<String> horariosLibres = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Integer horario : horariosTemporal){
        int hours = (horario / 60);
        int minutes = (horario % 60);
    String hours1 = null;
    String minutes1 = null;
        if(hours == 7 || hours == 8 || hours == 9){
            hours1 = "0" + hours + ":";
        }else{
            hours1 = hours + ":";
        }
        if(minutes == 5 || minutes == 0){
            minutes1 = "0" + minutes;
        }else{
            minutes1 = String.valueOf(minutes);
        }

        horariosLibres.add(hours1 + minutes1);

    }

    return horariosLibres;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Horario other = (Horario) obj;
    if (id == null) {
        if (other.id != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
        return false;
    return true;
}

}
```

And here the controller

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "horario")
    public class Horario implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private Long id;
        private Integer dia;
        private Integer horarioInicio;
        private Integer horarioFin;
        private Integer duration;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        @Column(name = "id")
        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        @Column(name = "dia")
        public Integer getDia() {
            return dia;
        }

        public void setDia(Integer dia) {
            this.dia = dia;
        }

        @Column(name = "horario_inicio")
        public Integer getHorarioInicio() {
            return horarioInicio;
        }

        public void setHorarioInicio(Integer horarioInicio) {
            this.horarioInicio = horarioInicio;
        }

        @Column(name = "horario_fin")
        public Integer getHorarioFin() {
            return horarioFin;
        }

        public void setHorarioFin(Integer horarioFin) {
            this.horarioFin = horarioFin;
        }

        @Transient
        public List<Integer> getHorarios(){
            List<Integer> horarios = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for(Integer i = horarioInicio; i <= horarioFin; i+=duration){
                horarios.add(i);
            }
            return horarios;
        }

        @Column(name = "duration")
        public Integer getDuration() {
            return duration;
        }

        public void setDuration(Integer duration) {
            this.duration = duration;
        }

        @Transient
        public List<String> getHorariosLibres(List<Integer> horariosTomados){

            List<Integer> horariosTemporal = getHorarios();
            horariosTemporal.removeAll(horariosTomados);
            List<String> horariosLibres = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (Integer horario : horariosTemporal){
                int hours = (horario / 60);
                int minutes = (horario % 60);
            String hours1 = null;
            String minutes1 = null;
                if(hours == 7 || hours == 8 || hours == 9){
                    hours1 = "0" + hours + ":";
                }else{
                    hours1 = hours + ":";
                }
                if(minutes == 5 || minutes == 0){
                    minutes1 = "0" + minutes;
                }else{
                    minutes1 = String.valueOf(minutes);
                }

                horariosLibres.add(hours1 + minutes1);

            }

            return horariosLibres;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                return false;
            Horario other = (Horario) obj;
            if (id == null) {
                if (other.id != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
                return false;
            return true;
        }

    }
```